# What command should I use for getting comprehensive service information on Powershell?

Tags: powershell, service

I need to make a RPC to retrieve and modify service statuses, on the basis of the "Log on as" field, as visible in the services UI.
The Get-Service command only provides me with the Status, Name, and DisplayName, but I need more information. Should I use a modifier with Get-Service, or is there another way of approaching the problem?

[log on field in Services UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MYFn.png)

Comment: Next time try using google before posting a question. The first page has plenty of examples... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/the-scripting-wife-uses-powershell-to-find-service-accounts/

Comment: Hi Doug. I did Google about this before asking the question here, though I unfortunately missed this, and was discouraged after looking at the MS Docs for Get-Service. Thanks for the additional resource, however! Will make sure to refer to devblogs from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Get-Service" provides you much more as you see by default.
Many Cmdlets have formatting definitions and show only particular properties by default.

You can see more on the top level (=direct members) by using "Format-List * -Force"

```
PS> Get-Service -Name 'BITS' | fl * -Force

UserName            : LocalSystem
Description         : Transfers files in the background using idle network bandwidth. If the service is disabled, then any applications that depend on BITS, such as Windows Update or MSN
                      Explorer, will be unable to automatically download programs and other information.
DelayedAutoStart    : True
BinaryPathName      : C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs -p
StartupType         : Manual
Name                : BITS
RequiredServices    : {RpcSs}
CanPauseAndContinue : False
CanShutdown         : False
CanStop             : False
DisplayName         : Background Intelligent Transfer Service
DependentServices   : {}
MachineName         : .
ServiceName         : BITS
ServicesDependedOn  : {RpcSs}
StartType           : Manual
ServiceHandle       :
Status              : Stopped
ServiceType         : Win32ShareProcess
Site                :
Container           :
```

But there are a lot of indirect (nested) members. You can discover them by using "Get-Member" or by using them them (e.g. `$service.RequiredServices`).

```
PS> $service | Get-Member -MemberType Property

   TypeName: System.Service.ServiceController#StartupType

Name                MemberType Definition
----                ---------- ----------
BinaryPathName      Property   System.String {get;set;}
CanPauseAndContinue Property   bool CanPauseAndContinue {get;}
CanShutdown         Property   bool CanShutdown {get;}
CanStop             Property   bool CanStop {get;}
Container           Property   System.ComponentModel.IContainer Container {get;}
DelayedAutoStart    Property   System.Boolean {get;set;}
DependentServices   Property   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[] DependentServices {get;}
Description         Property   System.String {get;set;}
DisplayName         Property   string DisplayName {get;set;}
MachineName         Property   string MachineName {get;set;}
ServiceHandle       Property   System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle ServiceHandle {get;}
ServiceName         Property   string ServiceName {get;set;}
ServicesDependedOn  Property   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[] ServicesDependedOn {get;}
ServiceType         Property   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceType ServiceType {get;}
Site                Property   System.ComponentModel.ISite Site {get;set;}
StartType           Property   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode StartType {get;}
StartupType         Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceStartupType {get;set;}
Status              Property   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus Status {get;}
UserName            Property   System.String {get;set;}
```

Here an extended view (up to 3rd level; there are much more)

```
[ServiceController] BITS
>   UserName                           : LocalSystem
>   Description                        : Transfers files in the background using idle network bandwidth. If the service is disabled, then any applications that depend on BITS, such as Windows Update or MSN Explorer, will be unable to automatically download programs and other information.
>   DelayedAutoStart                   : True
>   BinaryPathName                     : C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs -p
>   StartupType                        : [ServiceStartupType] Manual
>   >   value__                            : 3
>   Name                               : BITS
>   RequiredServices                   : @[ServiceController[]]
>   >   [0] <RequiredServices>             : [ServiceController] RpcSs
>   >   >   Name                               : RpcSs
>   >   >   RequiredServices                   : @{[ServiceController[]]} ~[0..2] RpcEptMapper , DcomLaunch
>   >   >   CanPauseAndContinue                : False
>   >   >   CanShutdown                        : False
>   >   >   CanStop                            : False
>   >   >   DisplayName                        : Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
>   >   >   DependentServices                  : 
>   >   >   MachineName                        : .
>   >   >   ServiceName                        : RpcSs
>   >   >   ServicesDependedOn                 : @{[ServiceController[]]} ~[0..2] RpcEptMapper , DcomLaunch
>   >   >   StartType                          : {[ServiceStartMode]} Automatic
>   >   >   ServiceHandle                      : 
>   >   >   Status                             : {[ServiceControllerStatus]} Running
>   >   >   ServiceType                        : {[ServiceType]} Win32ShareProcess
>   >   >   Site                               : 
>   >   >   Container                          : 
>   CanPauseAndContinue                : False
>   CanShutdown                        : False
>   CanStop                            : False
>   DisplayName                        : Background Intelligent Transfer Service
>   DependentServices                  : @[ServiceController[]]
>   MachineName                        : .
>   ServiceName                        : BITS
>   ServicesDependedOn                 : @[ServiceController[]]
>   >   [0] <ServicesDependedOn>           : [ServiceController] RpcSs
>   >   >   Name                               : RpcSs
>   >   >   RequiredServices                   : @{[ServiceController[]]} ~[0..2] RpcEptMapper , DcomLaunch
>   >   >   CanPauseAndContinue                : False
>   >   >   CanShutdown                        : False
>   >   >   CanStop                            : False
>   >   >   DisplayName                        : Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
>   >   >   DependentServices                  : 
>   >   >   MachineName                        : .
>   >   >   ServiceName                        : RpcSs
>   >   >   ServicesDependedOn                 : @{[ServiceController[]]} ~[0..2] RpcEptMapper , DcomLaunch
>   >   >   StartType                          : {[ServiceStartMode]} Automatic
>   >   >   ServiceHandle                      : 
>   >   >   Status                             : {[ServiceControllerStatus]} Running
>   >   >   ServiceType                        : {[ServiceType]} Win32ShareProcess
>   >   >   Site                               : 
>   >   >   Container                          : 
>   StartType                          : [ServiceStartMode] Manual
>   >   value__                            : 3
>   ServiceHandle                      : 
>   Status                             : [ServiceControllerStatus] Stopped
>   >   value__                            : 1
>   ServiceType                        : [ServiceType] Win32ShareProcess
>   >   value__                            : 32
>   Site                               : 
>   Container                          : 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use WMIC, it provides more info:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter 'name = "wuauserv"' | fl *
```